# Dynamically remove parent elements

Tags: asp.net, .net, vb.net

I have a .NET (vb) page that is rendered using 2 master pages and a few user controls.

My users now want a "print" button.

Is there a way to strip the main content out of the page, and re-render without all the master page and user control content?

Thanks

Comment: You need to consider the design that you have in place.  If you wish to 'strip' the master page content, then you need a page that doesn't subscribe to any master pages.  Nothing forcing you to use them (are they?).  Or else, you need to design it such that you can disable or turn off features of your master page.  Better yet, rather than adding content to the master page which is really conditional depending on the page, why not just have the page provide the content that IT needs - like adding a 'Control Panel' content placeholder which allows the page to provide the buttons.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use CSS to hide elements on the page when printing. There would be no need for a round trip to the server then.

```
@media screen 
{
   div.header {...}
}

@media print
{
   div.header {display:none;}
}

@media screen, print 
{
 ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could create a different masterpage then change to your 'alternate' stripped master which could include a print stylesheet.

There are some code samples at http://ipona.com/samples/ ( Bottom of the page links to a Skydrive folder at https://skydrive.live.com/?cid=635c8e2bf4822d7c&id=635C8E2BF4822D7C!498 )